# WinMobile emulator input issue in Windows8.1

Tags: emulation, tablet, windows-8.1, windows-mobile-6.1

I'm trying something very different. We have legacy Windows Mobile programs that we need to run on Windows 8.1 tablets with capacitive screens. To do this we've installed the stand alone Windows Mobile 6.1 Emulator which runs without a problem. Doing this, we can load and run our old Windows Mobile programs on the 8.1 Tablet and they run well but we are having problems with the touch or mouse click. The emulator is meant to be used with a mouse button to select and click not a touch screen. When we run our old programs we have to double-tap in order to select anything. This is not a problem until we try to enter text from the emulator keyboard. We have to tap each key twice in order to enter a character. This becomes very tiresome and makes the legacy program useless. Our legacy Win Mobile program was designed to allow our field people to collect large amounts of text and numeric data. Having to tap each key twice will not work.

We've examined the limited mouse and touch option in Windows 8.1 and nothing seems to help. So here are my questions:

1. Is there third party software that may improve on Windows 8.1 mouse customization? Synaptic maybe?
2. Is there a command line switch for the emulator we could add that would fix this problem?
3. Does anyone know of a method to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have asked this question to MS support.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17284
System Requirements: 
Supported Operating System
Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Vista, Windows XP Service Pack 3

Windows Mobile 6.5 Developer Tool Kit is not supported by Windows 8.x

My Double click test video 
http://youtu.be/0QIilCg1kxg

I think the problem is in Windows 8 touchscreen API driver, I have tested this emulator with Win7 tablet, no problems with double click.